# MySQL JSON: How to select MIN() value

Tags: mysql, json

I have a MySQL table:
The combo column is a JSON datatype

```
id | combo
1  | {"qty": "2", "variations": [{"name": "Cover", "value": "Paperback"}], "price": "14.00"}
2  | {"qty": "1", "variations": [{"name": "Cover", "value": "Hardback"}], "price": "7.00"}
3  | {"qty": "1", "variations": [{"name": "Cover", "value": "Paperback"}], "price": "15.00"}
```

I'm trying to get the `MIN()` price of `7.00` but as they're strings, it returns `14.00`.

Can this be done? Here's what I tried:

```
SELECT           
JSON_UNQUOTE(MIN(combo->'$.price')) AS min_price
FROM itemListings
GROUP BY id
```

I also tried removing the quotes around the stored prices but it gave the same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is giving you the *lexicographical* minimum; when sorting strings a `"1"` comes before a `"7"`, despite the strings being `"14.00"` and `"7:00"`, just like `"apple"` comes before `"bat"`, despite `"apple"` being longer than `"bat"`.

You want the *numerical* minimum, so cast the value to a decimal number:

```
SELECT
    id, -- you probably want the select the grouped by value too
    MIN(CAST(combo->'$.price' AS DECIMAL(10,2))) AS min_price
FROM itemListings
GROUP BY id
```